# Unity 2D RPG Healing from Potions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing developing a 2d top-down RPG game in Unity.
I am trying to implement a healing system where you heal some points when you buy a coffee. This is my healthManager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxHealth = 10;
    public int currentHealth;
    public HealthBarScript healthBar;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }
   
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            TakeDamage(1);
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);

        if(currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            currentHealth = 0;
        }
    }

    public void heal(int heal)
    {
        currentHealth += heal;
        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);

        if(currentHealth >= maxHealth)
        {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the script to buy coffee from a game object (sth. like a healing fountain):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class KaffeeautomatDialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dialogBox;
    public Text dialogText;
    public string dialog;
    public bool playerInRange;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && playerInRange)
        {
            if(dialogBox.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                dialogBox.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                dialogBox.SetActive(true);
                dialogText.text = dialog;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Player entered");
            playerInRange = true;
            var healthManager = other.GetComponent<HealthManager>();
          
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J) && playerInRange)
            {
                if(healthManager != null)
                {
                    healthManager.heal(5);
                    Debug.Log("You healed 5 Points!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Player left");
            playerInRange = false;
            dialogBox.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The Dialog Box shows up just fine and the Text is displayed. When i am staning in front of the healing fountain, i can activate and deactivate the dialog box by pressing "e".
But when i press "j", i don't heal and the console.log won't appear in Unity.

Did i mess up the Component import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking for an Input it should always happen inside the `Update()` method and not inside the `OnTriggerEnter2D()` because the OnTriggerEnter2D() method it will only executed everytime something gets inside the trigger which might happen only onces. On the other hand `Update()` it will be executed every single frame and check for an Input.

What you can do is the following, inside your `OnTriggerEnter2D()` method you need to have a global boolean variable that indicates that the player has entered the trigger and inside your `Update()` method when you check for the Input key "J" you need to check if the above boolean flag is true, if it is true then continue with the heal process. Also you need to make the flag false when the player exit the trigger.

From what I see you already have such flag `playerInRange`, you can write the following code:

```
public HealthManager healthManager;

void Update()
{
    if(playerInRange)
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if(dialogBox.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                dialogBox.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                dialogBox.SetActive(true);
                dialogText.text = dialog;
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if(healthManager != null)
            {
                healthManager.heal(5);
                Debug.Log("You healed 5 Points!");
            }
        }
    }
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player")) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Player entered");
        playerInRange = true;
        healthManager = other.GetComponent<HealthManager>();        
    }
}
```

Remove the Input check from your `OnTriggerEnter2D()` method.

Comment: Thank You Pavlos for that answer. Unfortunatly, that didn't fix the Issue.
When i try to access the healthManager, it doesn't know it inside the Update() Method, only in the OnTriggerEnter2D through the Collider2D other variable......

Comment: I've update the answer for your HealthManager script which basicaly I made it as a global variable and simple assign it when your OnTriggerEnter2D method executes, but this is not the best way to do it. What I would recommend is to either make your HealthManager script a singleton or simply drag and drop it from the editor and assign it into this script.

Comment: Thank's again for the help. I don't have that Error anymore, but the healing is still not user. Also, there is no console.log displaying the "You healed 5 Points!", so i think i still don't access the healthManager component of my player and i don't know why that is

Comment: Thank you Pavlor, i found my Error. I still had the "var healthManager" inside the OnTriggerEnter2D Method, so i tried to make a 2. because i have that already as a global variable....... Very Nice, now everything works fine!

Comment: I'm so glad to hear that everything worked out. Can you please mark the answer as useful to help me increase my reputation around here and to let anyone else who finds your post to know about the answer? Thank you

Comment: I have done that, you definitly deserve that!!!